# httplib2 :- argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'

Tags: python, django, linux, httplib2

I am using Google Indexing API, and I am getting this error

> argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'

I am implementing the API on the Django server when I run it on my local machine it runs just fine.
but when I put it on pythonanywhere it is giving me the above error. I don't know what's the reason for this error.
here is the function

```
def demo(request):
    context = {}
    if request.GET:
        link = request.GET.get('link')
        key = request.GET.get('key')

        if link and key:
            context = {
                'link': link,
                'key': key,
            }
            
            try:
                key = json.loads(key)
            except:
                return render(request, 'google_api_demo/index.html', context)
            scope = [ "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing" ]
            endpoint = "https://indexing.googleapis.com/v3/urlNotifications:publish"

            credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(key, scopes=scope)
            http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
            content = bytes(str({
              "url": f"{link}",
              "type": "URL_UPDATED",
            }), encoding='utf-8')
            response, content = http.request(endpoint, method="POST", body=content)
            context['response'] = response
            context['content'] = content
            return render(request, 'google_api_demo/index.html', context)

    return render(request, 'google_api_demo/index.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the [other cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65712911/google-sheets-api-not-working-on-pythonanywhere/65716277) that exception was raised by `PySocks` and upgrade `PySocks` solved it. Assuming that you run it outside the virtual environment with `python3.8` upgrade PySocs with `pip3.8 install --user --force-reinstall PySocks`